# Init multiple SKSpriteNodes

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, skspritenode

I'm trying to add multiple SKSpriteNodes to my SKSpriteNode subclass. In my case it is important that I can call the childNodes out of the Scene.

Is there a way to create such global available Sprites in a loop?

Comment: Sorry, I do not understand your question.  What do you mean with "it is important that I can call the childNodes out of the Scene"?  What is "calling" in this case?

Comment: @AntonBronnikov Sorry! I'm quite new to Xcode.. With the use of a loop I want to create multiple nodes in a custom SKSpriteNode-Class. Is there a way to set the alpha value of a specific child of that custom class object? Like: let object = CustomSpriteNodeClass(imageNamed"png")   -> object.aChildSprite.alpha = 0.5    Hope you'll understand what i mean .. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you add your sprites to the parent node remember to assign them a `name`

```
let parent = SKSpriteNode()

let child0 = SKSpriteNode()
child0.name = "child0"
parent.addChild(child0)

let child1 = SKSpriteNode()
child1.name = "child1"
parent.addChild(child1)

let child2 = SKSpriteNode()
child2.name = "child2"
parent.addChild(child2)
```

Later on you can retrieve them this way using the `name`

```
func foo() {
    guard let child1 = parent.childNodeWithName("child1") as? SKSpriteNode else { return }
    child1.alpha = 0.5
}
```